# How to get all possible URLs using .htaccess into one file?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to have an index.php file that controls who can access to each file accessed by the URL, so I decided to use the .htaccess file for that.

I tried both rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?get=$1
```

But as it seems that it makes a loop (as anubhava said) I also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^[^\?](.*)$ ?get=$1
```

But in both cases accessing to `?get=hello` I got "500 Internal Server Error" instead of getting the `hello` value.

Why? How could I get the full url into one file even if it's a reference to an existing file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is correct behavior. You are getting 500 internal error due to looping. Since URI pattern before and after rewrite is matching `.*`.

**Remember that mod_rewrite keep executing your rules as long as there is a matching rule.**

To overcome this looping issue you need `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?get=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which basically means that execute the rule only if request is not for a valid file or directory.

**EDIT:** As per your edited question, use this rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?get=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which basically means to rewrite only if `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` variable is not set. (**This variable is set to 200 after first successful rewrite by mod_rewrite module**).

**EDIT** (by axelbrz): I also added the `Options -MultiViews` line by anubhava to ignore the content negotiation module of apache that ruins the expected behaviour. Another possibility to ignore it is by disabling it running: `sudo a2dismod negotiation` and restarting apache.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to get all possibilities instead of which ones that start with "?", so I tried RewriteRule ^[^\?](.*)$ ?get=$1 and also get the 500 error. I will edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: Also take note of `[L]`, the [Last flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

Comment: @axelbrz: Yes do edit your question as query parameters require different mechanism not `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Your edited question can still be served well by my suggested answer.

Comment: If there is a file called script.js I also want to use ?get=script.js internally. How can I do that?

Comment: I also get "redirect:/" as the value when I try to access to "/script" and there is a script.js file.

Comment: It seems it's because of the content negotiation of Apache. I will try to disable it and checked it again.

Comment: Yes you should use `Options -MultiViews` for that.

Comment: Any specific reason you removed tick mark from the answer?

Comment: Yes, because as I found it was not complete I removed the tick. Now as it's complete I marked it again. The "Options -MultiViews" was an important line to make it work. I also tried disabling the content negotiation module running "sudo a2dismod negotiation" and restarting the apache and it worked too. Thank you!